# VSCode Prettier attribute formatting

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I'm using prettier to format my Vue files, but can't find to seem a setting that puts props/attributes of html elements to new lines.

[image: screen]

I'd like to make sure that my code is always formatted as it is for `v-text-field`in a yellow frame, rather than below. I set Prose Wrap to "never", but I guess that was not it. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the prettier extension or ESLint with prettier plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the setting of Print Width to higher value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

That's what Prettier does: breaks lines if they get too long. It doesn't make sense to use Prettier if you don't need its line-breaking behavior as this behavior and Prettier are one and the same.